# Nhibernate empty query

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have next code

```
if (user != null)
  query = query.Where(item => item.User.Id == user.Id);
else if (equipment != null)
  query = query.Where(item => false);// TODO: Add logic for equipment
```

but NHibernate can't build expression tree for `item => false`. Someday this expression will change, but now it must return empty query. Is there some method to solve this problem?

Comment: `WHERE(1 = 0)` will work

Comment: @stuartd , no. same exception. "Could not determine member type from Constant, False, System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression"

Comment: sorry, I was sure I'd used that in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is an IQueryable of User, try this.

```
if (user != null)
  query = query.Where(item => item.User.Id == user.Id);
else if (equipment != null)
  query = new List<User>().AsQueryable();
```

Edit:

OP said it is a IQueryOver not an IQueryiable, had a look at source and QueryOver is protected so can't see how to create an empty one easily right now. My suggestion is to use the LINQ provider if you can so my original answer will work. If it's not possible then this UGLY hack will work for now.

```
if (user != null)
                query = query.Where(item => item.User.Id == user.Id);
            else if (equipment != null)
                query = query.Where(item => item.User.Id < 0 && item.User.Id > 1);
```

Comment: AsQueryable() returns IQueryable object, but query is IQueryOver =(

Comment: Assumption is the mother of all mistakes. Is there a reason you're not using nHibernate's LINQ provider? Generally much nicer if not as powerful. There may be a nicer way but for now you can do this. if (user != null)
                query = query.Where(item => item.User.Id == user.Id);
            else if (equipment != null)
                query = query.Where(item => item.User.Id < 0 && item.User.Id > 1);

Comment: Thanks! Id is Guid, so I use next expression: query = query.Where(item => item.Id == Guid.Empty);

Answer (score 0):

I think I've used

```
  Where(item => 1 == 0)
```

Comment: Same exception. "Could not determine member type from Constant, False, System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression". Probably, NHibernate calculates expressions with constants, so we get ours Where(item=>false);